# Why is form_for, with custom params and no url helpers, outputting the wrong action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, Forums and Topics. I also have custom parameters in my routes, :permalink instead of :id for example.

My routes:

```
resources :forums, :param => :permalink do
  resources :topics, :param => :permalink
end
```

This results in:

```
forum_topics_path      GET   /forums/:forum_permalink/topics(.:format)   topics#index
                       POST  /forums/:forum_permalink/topics(.:format)   topics#create
new_forum_topic_path   GET   /forums/:forum_permalink/topics/new(.:format)   topics#new

# and some others
```

My form view:

```
<%= form_for([@forum, @topic], :url => {:forum_permalink => @forum.permalink, :permalink => @topic.permalink}) do |f| %>
  <!-- some elements -->
<% end %>
```

The form_for helper outputs the incorrect action path. For example, the new action view displays the form as:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/forums/atque-velit/topics/new" class="new_topic" id="new_topic" method="post">
```

Why doesn't Rails use the correct action? Am I missing a url option?

Comment: What's incorrect in here, I don't see anything wrong?

Comment: The action path should be /forums/atque-velit/topics. There is no route for a POST action at /forums/atque-velit/topics/new.

Comment: ah, sorry, obviously!

Answer (score 0):

**Original Suggestion**

Try:

```
<%= form_for([@forum, @topic], :url => forum_topic_path(@forum.permalink, @topic.permalink)) do |f| %>
```

**Edit**

You can sort of get there with `polymorphic_path`, though for some reason that will try to put `.<id number>` at the end of the URL when using custom parameters.

```
polymorphic_path([@forum, @topic], { forum_permalink: @forum.permalink, permalink: @topic.permalink })
```

produces something like:

```
/<forums>/<forum_permalink>/<topics>/<permalink>.<forum id>
```

You can get around that by forcing the format option to nil:

```
<%= form_for([@forum, @topic], url: polymorphic_path([@forum, @topic], { forum_permalink: @forum.permalink, permalink: @topic.permalink, format: nil })) do |f| %>
```

But that's getting a little bit messy.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually using a polymorphic association, so I can't use url helpers. I tried not making this an XY problem, but maybe I have.